# Auto-renewable subscription model

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Well, I am working on app, which is a basically free app to download, but the user has to sign-up through the app through an auto-renewable subscription.

Also every time when the user tries to log-in, my app will check for the subscription.

When the user tries to sign-up with the same user and but on another iOS device (with the different iTunes account), he/she has to buy the subscription again, as the device has the different iTunes account.

Along with that, if the user has bought the subscription from an Android device, he/she has to buy it again for the same username, if he/she wants to use it on an iOS devive and vice versa.

Now I am wondering whether this subscription model will be approved by Apple or not.

Or should I just change the subscription model to non-renewable subscription.

Thanks in advance.

-Shoan

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want the user to pay for his subscription multiple times? Probably not...

You should manage the account on your server. If the user buys from the store when logged in, update your server data to reflect his extended membership. And it's your server that decides whether the subscription is still valid or not.

It really shouldn't matter which iTunes account or device he uses to buy/extend his membership.

Comment: Do you know is Apple/Google OK with this type of implementation? I mean, a user making the payment through another platform and using the app on their platform.